# Pinia issue of incompatibility with Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, pinia

Hello I'm currently having issues with the integration of pinia in Nuxt3 whenever I run `npm run dev` it give me a warning.

```
WARN  Module pinia is disabled due to incompatibility issues:
 - [bridge] Nuxt bridge is required

ℹ Parsed 1 files in 0.3 seconds
```

I have tried double checking the installations of pinia and making sure I was running nuxt 3. Am I mistaken is Nuxt bridge part of Nuxt 3? I'm pretty new to Nuxt development. I installed pinia via `npm install @pinia/nuxt`

My nuxt config

```js
buildModules: [
  '@nuxt/typescript-build',
  '@nuxtjs/stylelint-module',
],

modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/axios',
  '@nuxt/content',
  '@pinia/nuxt',  
  'nuxt-buefy',
],

axios: {
  // Workaround to avoid enforcing hard-coded localhost:3000: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/308
  baseURL: '/',
},
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start ",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.ts,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"**/*.{css,scss,sass,html,vue}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:style && npm run lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && npm run lint:js -- --fix && npm run lint:style -- --fix",
    "prepare": "",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,vue}": "eslint --cache",
    "*.{css,scss,sass,html,vue}": "stylelint",
    "*.**": "prettier --check --ignore-unknown"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.6",
    "core-js": "^3.25.3",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.24",
    "vue": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.7.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.19.1",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^17.1.2",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.1.0",
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.8",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.1.2",
    "eslint": "^8.24.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.5.1",
    "jest": "^29.1.2",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.1.2",
    "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
    "postcss-html": "^1.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "pug-plain-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "sass": "^1.56.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.4.1",
    "stylelint": "^14.13.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-vue": "^1.4.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^28.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^29.0.3",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: It may be a good option to raise your concern directly to contributors of the third party package you're using. Here is where you can start - https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues

Comment: How do you import the module? [Like that](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/tree/v2/packages/nuxt#usage)? Mind sharing your nuxt config file + `package.json`?

Comment: `"nuxt": "^2.15.8"` looks quite Nuxt2 to me.

Comment: Thank you your right it was an issue with the version I thought I had updated correctly originally.

Comment: Works with Nuxt3?

Comment: yes it does after I made the change in the package.json

Answer (score 1):

You also need to install Pinia itself

```
yarn add pinia @pinia/nuxt
```

## or with npm

```
npm install pinia @pinia/nuxt
```

> **package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.4.7",
    "pinia": "^2.0.33",
  },
```

> **nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    modules: ['@pinia/nuxt'],      
});
```

> **Source:** https://pinia.vuejs.org/ssr/nuxt.html